# Row split problem of a table

Tags: tables

[image]

```
     \documentclass{beamer}
      \usepackage{mathtools}
      \usepackage{array}
      \usepackage{rotating,amsmath,booktabs,graphicx}

      \usepackage{amsmath}
      \usepackage{tabularx}


      \usepackage{tikz}
      %\usetheme{Boadilla}

       \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

       \usetheme{Warsaw}

      \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!black}
       \begin{document}

       \begin{frame}

       \begin{table}[]
       \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
       \hline
        \textbf{Har class Class} & \textbf{XYZ (in words)}   & 
      \textbf{Truple}    \\ \hline
    General vktm        & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
     It is only a text          & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
     Grfingiignigijfi \\jnferf    & $\mathcal{O}(n)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
   jvjtntg   & $\mathcal{O}(n)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
    frcjnrtgvtng  & $\mathcal{O}(n)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}






    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Question : There is a break in the table. I am getting how to fix it?

Comment: Your table does not support line breaks so `Grfingiignigijfi \\jnferf ` is wrong no matter what. ``\\`` will always make a new row in the table. For columns that supports forced line breaks in the cells one would use `\newline`, but `l` columns does not support line breaks in cells. Perhaps you should explain what your end goal is instead

Answer (score 1):

As @daleif already stated in a comment, `\\` will always create a new row. You can use `\newline` but also for columns that support multipe lines like `p`, `m`, `b`, etc. In your case, you can use `\makecell[l]{..}` in a left-aligned column. You need to add the `makecell` package, of course.

```
     \documentclass{beamer}
      \usepackage{mathtools}
      \usepackage{array,makecell}
      \usepackage{rotating,amsmath,booktabs,graphicx}

      \usepackage{amsmath}
      \usepackage{tabularx}


      \usepackage{tikz}
      %\usetheme{Boadilla}

       \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

       \usetheme{Warsaw}

      \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!black}
       \begin{document}

       \begin{frame}

       \begin{table}[]
       \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
       \hline
        \textbf{Har class Class} & \textbf{XYZ (in words)}   & 
      \textbf{Truple}    \\ \hline
    General vktm        & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
     It is only a text          & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
     \makecell[l]{Grfingiignigijfi \\jnferf} & $\mathcal{O}(n)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
   jvjtntg   & $\mathcal{O}(n)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
    frcjnrtgvtng  & $\mathcal{O}(n)$ & $\mathcal{O}(1)$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you liked :-):

[image]

No vertical rules, horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package, rearranged preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!black}

\usepackage{mathtools}% it also load "amsmath"
\usepackage{array,booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{rotating} % graphicx is loaded by "beamer"
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My table \dots}
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{ l *{2}{>{$}c<{$}} }
    \toprule
\thead{Har class Class} 
    &   \text{\thead{XYZ (in words)}}   
        &   \text{\thead{Truple}}           \\ 
    \midrule
General vktm       
    &   \mathcal{O}(1)  &   \mathcal{O}(1)  \\ 
It is only a text          
    &   \mathcal{O}(1)  &   \mathcal{O}(1)  \\
\makecell[l]{Grfingiignigijfi \\jnferf} 
    &   \mathcal{O}(1)  &   \mathcal{O}(1)  \\
jvjtntg   
    &   \mathcal{O}(1)  &   \mathcal{O}(1)  \\
frcjnrtgvtng 
    &   \mathcal{O}(1)  &   \mathcal{O}(1)  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: `graphicx` package is among set of packages loaded by `beamer`.

Comment: Is there any way to put horizontal lines between two consecutive rows.

Comment: @niceguy, of course. Just put `\midrule` between selected rows. However, before doing this, please consider, that in table design is *less is more*, see https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/